# Which files to select when doing a Windows 7 system restore from external hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, windows-backup

I have an ASUS computer running Windows 7 Home Premium and I am attempting to test my system backup/restore. I created the recovery DVD and system backup images (from the tools included with the OS) which I stored on an external hard drive.

When I attempt to test the backup, the boot from DVD is successful, and I can locate the folder for the system images on the external drive. However, the Windows restore program is now asking for the name of the file (of type Setup Information). The image folder contains three folders - Backup{date}, Catalog, SPPMetadatCache, and a file named MediaId. I've tried selecting almost all of the files, but none will work.

Which file(s) should I select?

Comment: +1 for testing your backup solution, not enough people do (me included)

Comment: Try creating the rescue DVD from the currently installed OS. if it's a slightly different version (even service pack) than the rescue partition that came with your laptop, the rescue might not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend using WAIK and using imagex instead. It's a free Microsoft Imaging solution.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753

Here is a decent video on building a winPE bootdisc:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQGujsHcq6U

From the WinPE boot disc:

CAPTURE `imagex /capture d: d:\imaging\data.wim "Drive D" /verify`

You can even mount the image from windows to access files inside the image.

MOUNT `imagex /mount d:\imaging\data.wim 2 c:\mounted_images`

APPLY `imagex /apply d:\imaging\data.wim 1 d:\New_Directory /verify`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx

Since you're only backing up and restoring your PC, you dont need to worry about an answer file or running sysprep for that matter.